# Welche der Anzeigen ist für wen interessant .... Michael der gelernter Architekt ist, aber lieber alte Möbel restauriert?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Welche der Anzeigen ist für wen interessant... Michael, der gelernter Architekt ist, aber lieber alte Möbel restauriert?

Why the verb "restauriert" comes at the end of the question? "der gelernter Architekt ist" is a relative clause; so I thought the construction of the sentence would be:

> Michael, der gelernter Architekt ist, restauriert aber lieber alte Möbel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the last part is a second relative clause.

> Für Michael, der lieber alte Möbel restauriert?

would also be a valid sentence.
A Variation of your sentence that makes its structure a bit more clear would be

> ...Michael, der ein gelernter Architekt ist, welcher aber lieber alte Möbel restauriert?

An interesting point in this variation is, that here the second relative clause addresses to "Architekt" and not to Michael:

> Michael ist ein Architekt, der aber lieber alte Möbel restauriert.

But this is just for further thoughts. The answer to this question is simply in the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The second part of your example (after ...) isn't a relative clause modifying a main clause. It's a relative clause with two verbs connected via "aber", and *no main clause*. That's why the verb stands at the end of either clause.

Comment: I do not agree here. In my understanding *"Michael*" is the main clause.

Answer (score 1):

Im Deutschen steht das Verb am Ende des Nebensatzes. Die Antwort bezieht sich auf die Frage und hat deswegen den Hauptsatz zu *Michael* verstümmelt. Mit vollständigem Hauptsatz könnte die Frage so lauten:

> Welche der Anzeigen ist für Michael interessant, der gelernter Architekt ist, aber lieber alte Möbel restauriert?

Der im zweiten Satz wurde der zweite Nebensatz zum Hauptsatz gemacht, was man sieht, wenn man den Nebensatz weglässt:

> Michael restauriert aber lieber alte Möbel.

Dieser Satz ist auch keine Frage, weil Fragen mit einem Verb oder Fragewort beginnen.